# How to cause Subdatasheet to display with Form's Datasheet view

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In my database is a Form based on a query which has a subdatasheet defined.  When the Form is in DataSheet view, each record shows the plus sign which can be expanded to show related records according the subdatasheet defined on the source query.  In other words, the Datasheet view automatically shows the Subdatasheet--as expected and as desired, so I know it can function like this.

I then created a new Form based on the same query as the existing, working Form.  However, the new Datasheet view will not show the Subdatasheet... no plus sign, nothing.  Next I created a test database with a couple related tables, and I also ensured that the tables have a Subdatasheet defined.  If I open the tables directly I see the plus signs and Subdatasheet as expected.  But once again if I define a form on those tables, it will not show the Subdatasheet when viewed in Datasheet mode.  There is no separate setting for an Access Form to define the Subdatasheet, rather it can only inherit the Subdatasheet setting from its record source object (i.e. table or query).

Is there any way to force a Form (in Datasheet view) to show the Subdatasheet already defined on the record source object?  Why might the new form function differently than the original even when it's based on the same query?

I'm using Access 2013 and database with 2007-2013 file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subdatasheet view is only available in DataSheet view.

Also it is recommended to use Subdatasheet view for only reading and not editing as unexpected errors may result.

From Microsoft:

> If you add subdatasheets to your tables, limit the use of these
>   subdatasheets to viewing, and not editing, important business data. If
>   you want to edit data in a table, we recommend that you use forms to
>   edit the data instead of subdatasheets, as data entry errors are more
>   likely to occur in datasheet view if users are not careful to scroll
>   to the correct cell. Also note that adding a subdatasheet to a large
>   table can adversely affect the performance of the table.
>
> Microsoft Office Access automatically creates a subdatasheet when you
>   create a table that matches one of the following criteria:
>
> The table is in a one-to-one relationship.
>
> The table is the "one" side of a one-to-many relationship, where the
>   table's SubdatasheetName property is set to Auto.
>
> A relationship is defined by matching the primary key and the foreign
>   key fields in the related tables.
>
> You can also add a subdatasheet to any table, query, or form in a
>   database. In Datasheet view, a form can display only one subdatasheet
>   at a time.

Comment: I typed Datasheet "mode" rather than "view"--my bad. It's now corrected, otherwise I explained it very carefully to avoid confusion. Yes, I know that a Subdatasheet is only for Datasheet view, but a Form is used to develop and make such a Datasheet view... as I described.  Thanks for the other tip, but I also said nothing about the use of the Datasheet... incidentally it will be read only.  If you had read my question carefully, you'll see that I have a problem duplicating something that already works, so the Microsoft detail doesn't help since my case already matches the proper conditions.

Comment: Ok you created a new Form with default view of Datasheet with same query as before. Now grab the related table (Subdatasheet part) drag it onto the Form. A popup will open where you can define the link fields. Now when you open it in Datasheet view you will have what you want I believe. Perhaps the subform is hidden on the original Form??

Comment: Thank you!  Yes indeed, I had a hidden subform--not only hidden but resized to a small box and moved into a corner of the Design view.  I had forgotten about that and had incorrectly recalled that the Subdatasheet behavior was automatic if already defined on the Record Source.  I searched everywhere, but didn't think to look at every element ON the form for the answer-stupid oversight.